Handle 100K request per second
How can i design a system that handle 100k req/s at peak time, each request performs an update of an object within 20kb size?
I used nodejs as backend for non blocking io, write-behind pattern with redis as cache and mongodb as db, but it handles only 10k req/s at peak.

You need to load balance and horizontally scale. See here also. You need 2 load balancers and maybe 14 "regular" servers to handle 100K requests.

suppose the infras is only my computer: cpu 4 cores 8 threads, 16gb ram, is there other way to optimize my system performence

Well, you need to purchase or rent servers that are designed efficiently for these tasks. Because, you need to buy 14 PCs or more because PCs are not efficient. You can maybe find used servers. But, you can't do it with one PC. 10K is too far from 100K.

I am not an expert of this but AFAIK mainstream PC CPUs are not really designed for this and dozens of Kreq/s seems normal IMHO on such machine. 100Kreq means <40 µs req per core which is pretty small for the tool you use, and several syscalls to do which generally take few µs each on mainstream CPUs. I guess you can reach such a performance with highly-optimized native tools using optimized OS APIs (which often possibly means less features, higher complexity and higher maintenance cost). You can profile what are the bottlenecks so to push the limit a bit further but certainly not 10x.

That requirement probably should have been at the top of the list of considerations when designing the system. You could try coding a simple bespoke key-value 'database' in a fast language like c. If you can cache enough of it in RAM, you may be able to update objects at peak rates in the millions per second on a single modest PC once you have the work in memory. Getting the work from a TCP socket as well might slow things down a lot. I don't know what you should expect from that.

if your hardware resources are enough but you want to optimize your application you may consider some of the techniques bellow
Cluster Module : use the cluster module of nodejs to get some advantages of multi core system this will allows you to create multiple instance of your application each of them is running on a CPU core
Worker : for the expensive operations task(CPU bound)  consider to use the worker threads this can separate task to multiple thread which able the main event loop responsible for other async task
Job managers : You can using job managers like bull to do some operations  in the background by adding them to a queue
compression : you can using compression technique to reduce the data size use a good compress algorithm like Gzip or Brotli
